# Using HMAC with SHA-1

Tags: java, bouncycastle, sha1, hmac, hmacsha1

I am attempting to implement HMAC using SHA-1 as the base. Using SHA-1 algorithm from bouncy castle, and implement the HMAC computation. Also to use SHA-1 to hash the input password to get the key for the HMAC algorithm.  I've been trying to do this for a few hours but I really have a poor understanding of HMAC.  If anyone has any tips on how to do this it would be appreciated.  My code below is my implementation of SHA1, via a library function call,  I'm essentially just trying to implement it with HMAC.

```
public class HMACSHA1 {
static byte[] password;
static byte[] fileName = null;
static byte[] input = new byte[16];
static String File;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Security.addProvider(Security.getProvider("BC")); 
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    File = args[1];
    try {
        password = args[0].getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unable to read password");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    InputStream inputstream = null;
    try {
             inputstream = new FileInputStream(File);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("No input found\n");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    MessageDigest hash = null;
    MessageDigest key = null;
    try {
        hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1", "BC");
        key = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1", "BC");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    key.update(password);
    byte[] HMACKey = key.digest();
    byte[] digest = null;
    int reader = 0;
    while (reader != -1){
        try {
            reader = inputstream.read(input);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        hash.update(input);
        digest = hash.digest();
        System.out.println(new String(Hex.encode(digest)));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Bouncy Castle, but you can work out the HMAC-SHA1 without external libraries using only what is provided with Java SE:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public String getHmacSha1(byte[] key, byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA1");

    Mac mac = null;
    mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(signingKey);
    byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(input);

    return Hex.encodeHexString(digest);
}
```

This is available since Java 1.4 according to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html).